# How do I deal with multiple kml files for one map?

Tags: carto, kml

I'm looking for general guidance on how to approach a simple map. 
I have a spreadsheet of seven schools, with fields such as "number of students" and "school budget". 
The catchment area for each school is its own KML file. 
What I want to do is build a map showing the seven catchment areas in my city, with pop-ups showing the school data for each area. 
What's the best way to structure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your catchment areas are not going to change that much I would recommend to merge all of them in a single file **before** uploading to CARTO. You can use any GIS tool for this like QGIS. You'll find plenty of information googling that.

Once you have both datasets, it's easy to join both datasets using the dedicated analysis *[Add Columns from Second Dataset](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/add-columns-from-second-dataset/)*.